# When use both WHERE IF DESC and LIMIT by Mybatis, IDEA shows Unable to resolve table 'LIMIT'

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, mybatis

Please forgive my poor English...

I want to use spring, spring-mvc and mybatis to build a website.

When I write mybatis.xml like below

```xml
    <select id="queryShopList" resultMap="shopMap">
        SELECT * FROM tb_shop s
        <where>
            <if test="shopCondition.area != null">
                AND s.area_id = #{shopCondition.area.areaId}
            </if>
        </where>
        ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 0, 5
    </select>
```

LIMIT was marked by red and IDEA shows me "Unable to resolve table 'LIMIT'",
but this mapper still could be used to pass the unittest.

and I've tried when I remove `<where>...</where>` content or `<if>...</if>` content ,even `DESC`, the error disappear.

I think maybe in this situation. IDEA think LIMIT is a table and give me a error.

But I don't know how to change this error message.I've no idea about this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Might be the "if" condition is wrongly placed.

```
<select id="queryShopList" resultMap="shopMap">
        SELECT * FROM tb_shop s
      <if test="shopCondition.area != null">
        <where>
                s.area_id = #{shopCondition.area.areaId}
        </where>
     </if>
        ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 10, 5;
    </select>
```

Comment: Try now. I modified the sql all together.

Comment: the same error message. I think it may be wrong about prompt by idea . because the sql work well. and I write sql the same as  this [standard](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use "Generic" **SQL** language in the [injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html) of this xml fragment:

[image]

IDE then will not validate the tables for resolve but will just highlight sql keywords.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this solution.It works well. but as you said, ide couldn't be able to  complete the tables.